# Why was the massive Human Wave attack used in WWI?

Tags: world-war-one, tactics, battle

If the [Human Wave Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_wave_attack) wave tactic is in all the lights, a invitation to a carnage, why was it so largely used in battles in WWI? Weren't other tactical options available at the time that could have been used ?

Comment: I suspect that any reference to "tactical options" requires that you make your question more specific.  Each tactical situation requires evaluation of different factors to decide  how to attack.

Comment: Welcome to SE. I'm refocusing your question to be specific to WWI, as I think that makes it a much better question. If that really isn't what you want, feel free to open it back up some (although that may risk more close votes).

Comment: Preliminary Bombardment, Chlorine Gas, Flame-Throwers, Creeping barrage, Tanks, Tunnelling Mines and Infiltration. There was a lot of tactical development in the ww1 and the premise of the question is a little unfair.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WWI was a pivotal time in military tactics due to the number of technological advances in warfare that had been relatively unused until that point in time.  Machine guns had developed to a point that isn't much different from modern designs; field artillery had gotten a lot bigger, was capable of indirect fire, and had many different munition options; chemical weapons were available; airplanes were starting to become a valuable asset; and mainline infantry was now outfitted with very powerful and accurate repeating rifles. This combined to create a killing power that had previously been unimaginable.

Before this period massive charges were effective because it was possible to close on an enemy with a large force before the enemy could decimate it, allowing you to break their line and limit the effectiveness of their heavy weaponry. It was used so much, because that was the strategy taught to officers at the time, because that is what had historically worked for large armies. Other strategies had largely yet to be implemented, or were similarly useless against new technology.

There actually was a surprising amount of new strategies developed in WWI, some genius others less so. There was a lot of catch-up being played by officers on all sides to devise new strategies for the modern era.

Comment: Another important technological breakthrough for WWI was the communication technology. The telephone enabled higher-ups to communicate with and command the field officers directly, while being physically distant from the action. It enabled insistence on the "tried and true" approaches in a changed world.